# Difference between Dual and Auto option in debugging

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, android-debug

What is the Difference between Dual and Auto option in debugging in Android Studio 3.0.
Earlier Android Studio (<3.0 , from 2.2 ) there used to be Hybrid and Auto?Why change name?
What to choose for Native debugging? Auto or Dual?

Answer (score 0):

In my android studio 3.0 canary 4, it has 2 types of debugger `Java` and `Auto`. Documents describing them is available [Debug Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html) please go through it.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio has 2 debuggers,one for java and one for native C/C++. It has 4 debug types.

**Auto** automatically chooses the best debugger. For example,if your code contains only java,it will use only the java debugger. But if your code contains C/C++ ,it will use **Dual** which is basically using both the debuggers,

You can also choose to use only the Java Debugger or the Native Debugger on its own.

Comment: even on selecting the Auto option will it select Dual internally/Automatically if I am using the native code within? I dont think so.

Comment: "If you have any C or C++ code in your project, Android Studio automatically uses the Dual debug type. Otherwise, Android Studio uses the Java debug type." -this is from the user guide. This is when it is set to auto.